# Comparing skin temperature to environment

Tags: correlation

I have recorded animal skin temperatures (animals kept in fairly constant conditions) over a time period, and also the ambient humidity and temperature at the same time. What test(s) would I use to see if  ambient temp. and humidity may have affected the animals skin temp, and why?
And yes, Im very new to statistics :-(
Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Linear regression is good for you. The animal skin temperatures will be response variable (dependent variable)and ambient humidity and temperature will be covariates (independent variables).

If you get the animal skin temperatures, the ambient humidity and temperature more than one time from the same animal (repeated measurement), you need to consider the correlation between measures. Maybe you can use AR(1) structure to deal with this correlation.

If your animals were in the different cages and one cage had multiple animals, maybe you need to treat the effect of cage as random.